# Simple explanation of expanding universe, red shift and time difference between galaxies

Tags: cosmology, universe, big-bang

Given that the red shift of galaxies increases with distance, and that the light from further galaxies has taken longer to travel - then it seems that comparing red shift between galaxies needs to account for the difference in time that the light has travelled.

Is there a simple way to refute the argument that the red shift of further away galaxies is due to observing light from longer ago when the galaxies were moving faster away from each other?

Comment: You may enjoy this [Big Bang / expansion article](https://people.smp.uq.edu.au/TamaraDavis/papers/SciAm_BigBang.pdf) by Tamara Davis and Charles Lineweaver. That article is a simplified version of their classic paper, [Expanding Confusion: common misconceptions of cosmological horizons and the superluminal expansion of the Universe](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0310808).

Comment: I did not understand your question